# How to authenticate a User

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-login, django-custom-user

I have created two different types of users - truck & company. Here is my registration page for a user [image]

After registering, the data about whether the user is a truck or company will go to the database.

In my login page, [image: LoginPage]

only Email and Password are to be entered. In my custom user creation form, I added the field username = email.

When I am trying to login with valid credentials, the page is not redirecting me to a particular page according to the user-type. Instead, an error which I created for invalid credentials in login.html is raising - "Your email and password didn't match. Please try again."

here's my code:

views.py:

```
def login_view(request):
title = "Login"

if request.method == 'POST':

    form = LoginForm(data=request.POST)
    email = request.POST.get('email', '')
    password = request.POST.get('password', '')
    user = auth.authenticate(username=email, password=password)
    if form.is_valid():
        auth.login(request, user)
        user_type = form.cleaned_data['Label']
        if user.is_active & user_type == 'Truck':
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/post_load/')
        elif user_type == 'Company':
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/live_deal/')
else:
    form = LoginForm()

return render(request, 'registration/login.html', {'form' : form, 'title': title})
```

urls.py:

```
# url(r'^login/$', views.login_view),
# url(r'^accounts/login/$', views.login_view),
url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'authentication_form': LoginForm}),
url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'authentication_form': LoginForm}),
```

forms.py:

```
class LoginForm(auth.forms.AuthenticationForm):

email = forms.EmailField(label=_("Email"),widget=forms.EmailInput)
CHOICES= (('Truck', 'Truck'),('Company', 'Company'),)
Label = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, label='Label', widget=forms.RadioSelect())
```

login.html:

```
{%extends "registration/header.html"%}
{% block content %}
{% if form.errors %}
<p>Your email and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
{% endif %}

<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action = "." >{%csrf_token%}
<div class="panel panel-default login">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span> Login</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-4'>
                <table border="0">
                <div class="col-sm-4"> 

    <tr><th><label for="id_user" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Email:</label></th><td>{{ form.email }}</td></tr> </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"> 



    <tr><th><label for="id_password" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Password:</label></th><td>{{ form.password }}</td></tr> </div> 

</table> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-8">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox"/>
                            Remember me
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group last">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-8">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">
                        Sign in</button>
                    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/" /> 
                        <label class="col-sm-offset-3">
                 <a href="#">Forget Password? </a>
            </label> 
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
            Not Registered? <a href="/register/">Register</a></div>

</div>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: It's quite difficult to read incorrect indented python code

Comment: Should I provide any info about my code by briefly describing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
{% if form.errors %}
<p>Your email and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
```

This error is rather broad. You could loop through it to see the actual errors.

Better yet; don't use your own authentication system just use Django's built-in system which also allows you to add extra fields to the user model.

Example:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def my_view(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            # Redirect to a success page.
        else:
            # Return a 'disabled account' error message
            ...
    else:
        # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
        ...
```

Note, you don't need to write your own login view, you can also use Django's login system to handle the form, pass reset/change, urls and templates (which you can override with your own template):

urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url('^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

Then `/login/` will be your login page.

After it works with the Django contrib auth module, extend it with your own custom HTML login form.

[django.contrib.auth.views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views)

Comment: Thank you for kind answer. But, after logging in, I wanted to redirect a user to a particular page based on the user_type. So, I created a user_type in my login_view and trying to do that.  How can i do this in my_views.

Comment: when using the first example you can setup the redirect because you have access to the user variabele. When using the second approach; you could do it with a signal, or trigger the redirect from the view you configured as home.

Comment: what if i'm using my own user table !!

Comment: There are a couple of ways to customize the User or use your own User class: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/